# Symfony2 Child Form Events Propagation

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, event-listener

I have two entities. Entity A is a parent of Entity B. I am creating a REST for entity A which contains entity B as children.

```
class EntityA {
   private $name;
   private $type;

   private $bs;
}

class EntityB {
   private $entityA;
   private $color;
}
```

I basically do a post/put with something like:

```
{ "name": "anamehere", "type": "atypehere", "bs": [{"color": "blue"}] }
```

For the important part, the form of Entity A looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('type', TextType::class)
        ->add('bs', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => EntityB::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, array($this, 'onSubmitData'));

}

public function onSubmitData(FormEvent $event) {
    // Do Something
}
```

And my Entity B's form looks something like:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('color', TextType::class);

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, array($this, 'onSubmitData'));

}

public function onSubmitData(FormEvent $event) {
    // Do Something else
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when I do that POST/PUT the entity B form event onSubmitData is not being called. How can I propagate the event from the EntityA form to the EntityB form. It is working properly in EntityAType

Comment: How about attaching listener on event `POST_SUBMIT' but not to the whole subform but to bs field in Entity A form?

Comment: @PawełMikołajczuk That could work but I was looking for a more generic solution.. because imagine that the bs form had child forms itself.. or that the bs form gets used in multiple places.. I am trying to avoid repeating myself.. also I would have to define the functions in the EntityAType so if another form uses 'bs' I would have to repeat the functions

Comment: I get your point, but can't find anywhere information if Submit event is populated for for embedded forms ;/ Looks like it isn't but i'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same question as you had, and with a bit of tests I found the answer, so I'm answering here, in case somebody else finds his way here: There **IS** event propagation for Child form events.

The exact lifecycle is:

```
Parent PRE_SUBMIT
                     Child PRE_SUBMIT
                                        GrandChild PRE_SUBMIT
                                        GrandChild SUBMIT
                                        GrandChild POST_SUBMIT
                     Child SUBMIT
                     Child POST_SUBMIT
Parent SUBMIT
Parent POST_SUBMIT
```

About your problem, my guess is that it is caused by the fact you don't use directly EntityB's form in EntityA's form, but a CollectionType of EntityB's form type, and it seems that CollectionType does not naturally dispatch SUBMIT events for each for its children.

Hope this helps anyone!

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it is a very logical explanation regarding what's happening and it makes a lot of sense. That's what I ended up assuming and just moved on with another approach. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, here is the propagation order between siblings (e.g. if parent has Child1 and Child2):
1. Child1 PRE_SUBMIT
2. Child1 SUBMIT
3. Child1 POST_SUBMIT
4. Child2 PRE_SUBMIT
5. Child2 SUBMIT
6. Child2 POST_SUBMIT